# Find strings between << and >> that contain backslashes

Tags: regex, rtf, backslash

I am working in an RTF file where I have to insert tags in a custom markup language that a program replaces with data.  For example, in the file, I have:

```
Account number:  <<@Account.AccountNumber>>
```

I am editing this template in Microsoft Word 2007 and whenever I backspace, Microsoft word inserts a bunch of RTF garbage in the template so I get something like this:

```
<<@Am\hich\af1\dbch\af31505\loch\f1 ount>>
```

Instead of:

```
<<@Amount>>
```

How do I find wherever this happened?  I tried writing regular expressions to do this, but I don't know how to write them very well.  Here's one that I tried:

```
<<.+?\\.+?>>
```

But when I pass in this phrase:

```
<<Where: Phrase =\ @Value>>\<<hi>>\hi<<hi>>
```

The backslash after the "=" should be matched, but neither the backslash between the "<<Where>>" and "<<hi>>" tags nor the "\hi" between the "<<hi>>" tags should be matched (regex101.com and Notepad++ matches them).

I do not care if only the backslashes themselves are matched or the entire tags with backslashes in them are.  My end goal is just to be able to find them quickly in Notepad++ (or some other editor if that's necessary) so that I can fix them.

Comment: Try `(?s)<<(?:(?!<<).)*?\K(?:\\[a-z]\w*)+\s` to replace with empty string. I am not sure if that will work the way you expect if there can be multiple ``\``s inside the `<<>>`. Else, try `(?s)(?:<<|(?!^)\G)((?:(?!<<).)*?)(?:\\[a-z]\w*)+\s` to replace with `$1` if there can be many inside `<<...>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
<<[^\\>]*\\[^>]*>>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xG9bD7/2)

Explanation:

- `<<` the opening tag of your custom markup language
- `[^\\>]*` any number of characters that is not a `\` or a `>`
- `\\` a literal `\`
- `[^\\>]*` any number of characters that is not a `>`
- `>>` the closing tag of your custom markup language

---

*EDIT:* to match even when a `>` character can be inside the custom markup tag, you can use the following expression, which relies on atomic groups / possessive quantifiers to prevent catastrophic backtracking and keep the matches fast:

```
<<(?>(?>[^\\>]*)(?>>(?!>))?)*+\\(?>(?>[^>]*)(?>>(?!>))?)++>>
```

It's similar to the previous expression but includes:

- `(?>...)` atomic groups
- `(?>>(?!>))?` optionally match `>` if not immediately followed by another `>`
- `*+` any number of times + possessive quantifier
- `++` at least once + possessive quantifier

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xG9bD7/3)

Comment: This regex does not match `<<Text <text> @Am\hich\af1\dbch\af31505\loch\f1 ount>>`

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew, but luckily the markup language seems to be very simple and doesn't allow any nesting.  Keith's answer seems to work for me.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:  Oops, I spoke too soon.  The language does allow > and < operators in the Where clause and this doesn't work for <<Where: Column > Value>>

Comment: @Sean, I have now updated my answer to cater for `>` inside the tags.

Comment: @KeithHall I'd give you another upvote if I could; thanks a bunch!